# PHP Sessions Variables on second Page

Tags: php, variables, session

Good day.I am trying to use session variables but can not seem to get it to work.
I attach my scripts.I do start the session in both
the first script Test.php looks like this

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";

?>
```

and the second script test1.php looks like this

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
                        
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run the first one,i get the message that the variables was set.But when i run the second script,it do not show the variables.It is just blank.

i realy would appreciate any help

Comment: what is `var_dump($_SESSION)` result?

Comment: in test.php   it shows                                              Session variables are set.array(2) { ["favcolor"]=> string(5) "green" ["favanimal"]=> string(3) "cat" }

Comment: and in test1.php                                                                 NULL Favorite color is .
Favorite animal is .

Answer (score 0):

The php code works fine for me. It must be something in your environment settings. You may want to check `.ini` file settings, or browser settings to make sure that it the browser is storing and sending the session id cookie with each request. Without that cookie, the server won't know which session to start.

Try running a file with `phpinfo()` and search through all the settings under `session`. That might point you in the direction of a .ini file issue. You can also open your browser dev tools and look at the application tab for your site. There should be a cookie stored for your site that correlates to the session name, probably `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: It does show PHPSESSID,but i can not find any .ini file .Is the variables saved in the session.save_path? In the session.save_path /usr/home/****/.tmp,           that folder is empty

Comment: i found the php.ini file. How do i get to that folder?

Comment: /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini